# Change background color text in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm working with PHP in Eclipse (PDT), but when there is code of HTML and PHP, the HTML color is with a black background and this is very annoying and difficult to read. Is there a way to change that background color?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring and then navigate through the list and find the ones that have the black background and change it back to white.

If the color preference isn't in there, search for Syntax Coloring and see if you have something else overriding it.

Comment: +1. Easier way: type color into the search bar of the preferences window. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks! the only problem is that I have to search colors of every attribute, everything has foreground white and background black.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing something similar to what jprofitt said, but less complete.

Another option would be to install the [Eclipse Color Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) plugin and use those settings.